# Prove that the function is uniformly distributed.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider discrete uniform random variable with distributions $$P(X_{n}=\frac{k}{n})=\frac{1}{n}$$ for $k=1,...,n$ Show that as $n \to \infty$ it has continuous density function $$f(x)=\cases{1\space 0\leq x \leq 1\\0\space otherwise }$$ Does it prove it if I show that their first and second moments are the same? If not how should I go around it?

Comment: $P\left(X^{n}=\frac{k}{n}\right)=\frac1n$ or  $P\left(X_{n}=\frac{k}{n}\right)=\frac1n$ ?

Comment: I suspect that you are really being asked to show that, for all real numbers $x$, we have  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Pr[X_n \leq x] = F_X(x)$, where $F_X(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of a uniform random variable $X$ in the interval $[0,1]$.  Can you work in that direction?  For example, if $x \geq 1$ we have $Pr[X_n \leq x] = Pr[X\leq x] = 1$ for all $n$, so that case holds.

Comment: It is $X_n$ sorry for misleading you.

Comment: Okey. So I need to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{X_n}(x)=F_X(x)$. But this is for continuous distribution functions.

Comment: $F_X$ is continuous; $F_{X_n}$ is not. But this is not a problem.

Comment: Can you do the following steps?  (a) Write down the $F_X(x)$ function for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  (b) Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Pr[X_n\leq x] = F_X(x)$ for all $x \geq 1$.  (c) Prove the same for all $x \leq 0$.  (d) Prove the same for $x \in (0,1)$.  You can post your own answer to this question below.

Comment: Okey will see where it leads,

Comment: So $F_{X_n}(t)=\cases{0\space t<0\\1/2-1/n\space 0\leq t<1\\1\space t\geq 1 }$ and $F_{X}(t)=\cases{0\space t<0\\1/2\space 0\leq t<1\\1\space t\geq 1 }$ If I let $n \to \infty$

Comment: The $F_X(t)$ function you give above is incorrect in the range $t \in (0,1)$. Also, it has nothing to do with $n$, or taking limits of $n$, it is the CDF function of a uniform random variable in $[0,1]$, so $F_X(x) = Pr[X\leq x]$. I'm not sure where your "1/2" is coming from.

Comment: My bad, tried to rewrite $X_n$ in terms of indicator function then to CDF

Comment: Should have been $t$ instead of 1/2

Answer (score 1):

One way is via the Characteristic Function.

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{ixt}] = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n} e^{i\frac{k}{n}t} = \frac{1-e^{it}}{n(e^{-it\tfrac{1}{n}} -1)}$$

Which holds by the formula for a geometric series. The limit of the denominator is $-it$. Which implies

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[e^{ixt}] = \frac{e^{it} - 1}{it}$$

Which is exactly the Characteristic function of a uniform random variable on (0,1). The result follows by uniqueness of the Characteristic functions and by uniqueness of the density function.